# Fourier sine series of cosine?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

In the middle of a PDE I'm trying to solve, I've gotten $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n(0) \sin(nx) = \cos(3x)$$

Is this even possible?  How can you expand a cosine (even) in terms of sines (odd)?  Did I necessarily make a mistake (I don't see one)?  If not, how could I solve for my $T_n$'s?

Comment: On what interval is the expansion? $[0,\pi]$ by any chance?

Comment: Can you include more context? What is the original PDE? What is the domain for $x$? You could have, for instance, a sine series converging to the odd-periodic extension (outside $[0,2\pi]$ or whatever) of cosine.

Comment: Yes.  On $[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find the coefficients in the usual way: $T_n(0) = \displaystyle \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin(nx) \cos(3x)\; dx$.

The reason odd/even doesn't cause a problem is that for a sine series, you
are implicitly extending the function from the interval $[0,\pi]$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$
so that it is **odd**, and then to the real line so it has period $2\pi$.
So really what you are approximating with odd functions is not $\cos(3x)$ but
$$ \cases{ \cos(3x) & for $0 < x < \pi$\cr
          -\cos(3x) & for $-\pi < x < 0$\cr}$$